# Ruby bundle exec silently fails to run gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have `Ruby 2.1.5p273` and `RubyGems v2.4.6` on `CentOS 7.1 x86_64`. When I run `bundle exec bin/awesome_app` I get no error on the screen, and my app doesn't run. However, with --verbose turned on, I see this:

```
$ bundle --verbose  exec bin/recall_app 
ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["exec", "bin/recall_app"]
Usage: "bundle install [OPTIONS]"
```

However, I've already ran `bundle install` in the directory of the gem. I'm not sure what else I would need to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use Bundle to execute the gem without actually installing it to test it out. Its a Sinatra web app.

Comment: Okay and what is `bin/recall_app`? To run a Sinatra app the syntax is generally `bundle exec ruby your_app_file.rb`. I don't see anywhere here where you are telling it to use ruby or where you are giving the file name. [Official Docs for Sinatra with Bundler](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#With%20Bundler)

Comment: You're right @engineersmnky, I stuck it in a rake file, had been using it so long that I forgot the actual command. Thank you. Could you post that as your answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your request: To run a `Sinatra` app with bundler the command is `bundle exec ruby your_main_app_file.rb`.

[Here are the official Docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#With%20Bundler)